# Devise validation of an email address returns: 'is invalid' to my client side validation

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am using the [judge gem](https://github.com/joecorcoran/judge) to do client side validation of form inputs, but I am having some problems validating the `email` attribute in my `User` model. I am using `devise`'s [validatable](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Validatable) module to perform validation of the uniqueness of the `email` as well as some regex validations I guess.

When using `judge` on my form, I get back this **'is invalid'** error when I enter any email into my form.

Any idea why this is?

My initializer:

```
Judge.configure do
  expose User, :email
end
```

My js:

```
judge.validate document.getElementById("user_email"),
  valid: (element) ->
    console.log "Good job"
  invalid: (element, messages) ->
    console.log messages.join(', ')
```

My form:

```
= form_for(resource, :builder => Judge::FormBuilder, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f|
  = f.text_field :email, :validate => true
```

My log:

```
Started GET "/judge?klass=user&attribute=email&value=my%40email.com&kind=uniqueness" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-03 18:44:37 +0200
Processing by Judge::ValidationsController#build as JSON
  Parameters: {"klass"=>"user", "attribute"=>"email", "value"=>"my@email.com", "kind"=>"uniqueness"}
Completed 200 OK in 5ms (Views: 0.2ms)
```

And when I remove the [validatable](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Validatable) module from my `User` model, no errors are returned.

Comment: any lead on the question?